# mysql errors to authenticate and create a table

Tags: mysql, bash

I have not been introduced to mysql, but had to work with it. I installed it and tried to run this:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE h7vsk1200001 (quid VARCHAR(15), suid VARCHAR(15), iden FLOAT, alen INT, mism INT, gapo INT, qsta INT, qend INT, ssta INT, send INT, eval FLOAT, bits INT);
```

Which I understand is the basis for a table, with its names for columns and its datatypes. Whenever I run it, I get this error message:

```
bash: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `('
```

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 if that matters. Also, if I try to run the CREATE TABLE command without arguments I get:

```
$ mysql> CREATE TABLE
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'carlos'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Consider that I have little experience with bash and no experience with mysql (as you may have denoted)

Comment: The query itself seems fine.

Comment: How you are running the `CREATE TABLE` command in BASH shell? give little background.

Comment: When installing mysql I was prompted to set a master password for it. Can I access that user?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to launch the `mysql` shell. You can't run queries like this in bash: you need to use a MySQL client. You're getting the first error because `bash` is trying to parse the parentheses, and the second error is the result of you running the `mysql` command while piping (`>`) the output to a new file called `CREATE`.

Note you're getting the `ACCESS DENIED` because you apparently don't have access as the user `carlos` without a password. Use `mysql -u myusername -p` to log in with username `myusername` and to have `mysql` prompt for a password.

```
thom@lethe-arch:~$ # bash shell
thom@lethe-arch:~$ mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 443
Server version: 10.0.14-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle, SkySQL Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> -- type queries here
```

(Note: MariaDB is a fork of MySQL and behaves exactly the same)

Comment: As I said in the other answer, I'm unabled to login in mysql. Am I supposed to enter the mysql shell just typing mysql (EDIT)in bash?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to create a user 'carlos' and allow necessary permissions like:

```
 mysql> use mysql;

 mysql> CREATE USER 'carlos'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';

 mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'carlos'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: I get an error with the first command but can run the rest, but I still can't login as said by @thom-wiggers with the password set with this code.